# How do I include a document that has a field is null in aggragation framework in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem, where I search for documents using Aggregation Framework, and one document has a field "place" set to null. As such, it is not returned from the database with my current code. My code is:

```
router.get("/search", async (req, res) => {
  const items = await Item.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "places",
        localField: "place",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "placeData",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$placeData",
    },
    {
      $match: {
        $or: [
          { title: new RegExp(req.query.searchQuery, "i") },
          { sku: new RegExp(req.query.searchQuery, "i") },
          { "place.title": new RegExp(req.query.searchQuery, "i") },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        title: 1,
        sku: 1,
        place: {
          $ifNull: ["$placeData", "Digital"],
        },
      },
    },
  ]);

  res.send(items);
});
```

Comment: I think that is by design. Do you really want to store null values in the db? I think you are meant to do a null check in the service that consumes this?

Comment: I have items collection, where some items can be digital or not. if it is digital, place is null

Comment: You can specify [multiple join conditions](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) with `$lookup`'s alternative syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I tweaked the "unwind" stage a bit, as follows:

```
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$placeData",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
```